# Redirect Traffic

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache2, vhosts

I want to redirect traffic in this way.

```
kevin.domain.com -> /var/www/kevin/domain.com/
thomas.example.com -> /var/www/thomas/domain.com/
kevin.subdomain.domain.com -> /var/www/kevin/subdomain.domain.com/
$user.$subdomain-and-domain -> /var/www/$user/$subdomain-and-domain/
```

But if the first part isn't a user (that means, the dir `/var/www/$user/` doesn't exist), it must redirect in this way:

```
domain.com -> /var/www/working/domain.com/
subdomain.example.nl -> /var/www/working/subdomain.example.nl/
$domain -> /var/www/working/$domain/
```

How can I archieve this?

Many thanks :D!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by configuring your virtual host, or using mod_rewrite.

Take a look here : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/mass.html

Both methods are explained. Come back if you have any trouble implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [mod_userdir](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_userdir.html) is interesting.